# Python: Organizing a Text File

Tags: python, file, text

I made a local text file that looks something like this:

```
   Houston 69.7 degrees F

   Brazosport 69.8 degrees F

   Miami 77.3 degrees F

   Carol City 77.3 degrees F

   North Westside 77.3 degrees F

   Hialeah 77.9 degrees F
```

And my task is to organize it alphabetically by the first letters.

Here is my attempt at it. I can't seem to get it though. My list contains cities starting with every letter in the alphabet.

```
for aline in mf2:
        f = ord('A') + x
        g = ord(aline[2])
        if g == f:
            mf3.write(aline)
            x = x + 1
mf3.close()
```

Comment: Shocking that Python does not have a sorted tree out of the box.

Comment: Why not just the `sorted()` function?: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Its not a list, so i can't use that sort function...but could i turn it into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be:

```
for aline in sorted(mf2):
    mf3.write(aline)
mf3.close()
```

Comment: That worked! Now I have to sort the list by the temperature values. Any ideas?

Comment: You got me haha. I just figured out the temperature thing though

Comment: Don't cheat. You only hurt yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small enough, you can create a list with each line as an element.
Here I filtered out the empty lines and stripped the spaces (left and right end) from each line. You can use lstrip() or rstrip() to strip from left or right end only.
test.txt contains exactly the entries you gave above.

```
def main():
    with open("test.txt") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
        lines = [line.strip(" ") for line in infile if line != "\n"]
        lines.sort()
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")# read the input text file  
# omit empty lines and lines containing only whitespace
lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()] # frame list with each line as element
f.close() # close the opened file as we are already read lines from file
lines.sort() # sorting the lines from list
output = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    output.write(line) # writing sorted lines to output file
output.close()
```

Comment: Please also explain the code with explicit text to be more educative.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I have updated answer with some comments